# Mkdocs doesn't generate ordered list

Tags: mkdocs

I am trying to use mkdocs to generate nested ordered list from markdown without success.
In the md file, I have the following:

> 1. first
> 2. second
>
>    1. A
>    2. B
> 3. third

The created web page shows:

> 1. first 2. second 1. A 2. B 3. third

I saw somewhere that I need to add in the `mkdocs.yml` file the line `- def_list` under `markdown_extensions:` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `material` theme for MkDocs. You can get more info from [Ordered nested lists docs](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/lists/#using-ordered-lists). In this case

```
1. first
2. second
   1. A
   2. B
3. third
```

Will be displayed as:

```
1. first
2. second
  a. A
  b. B
3. third
```